# Show category description evan there is no products in that category - Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How can i remove "No products were found matching your selection." and show category description even there is no products in that category?

Answer (score 0):

The template file that controls this is found in `woocommerce/templates/loop/no-products-found.php`. Make a copy of that in your theme's WooCommerce template override directory (`/wp-content/themes/my_theme_name/woocommerce/loop` in this instance). Within that copied template file, you should see:

```
<p class="woocommerce-info"><?php _e( 'No products were found matching your selection.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>
```

This may be different depending on your version of WooCommerce.

Change that part to:

```
<p><?php do_action('woocommerce_product_archive_description'); ?></p>
```

You can change the markup around that function as needed to get it looking the way you want.

Comment: Thanks Josh I found solution

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Josh but not working

I found solution at night

do_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description' ); works for me